# Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.ArrayList<LiveData<List<a>>> but Collection<LiveData<List<TypeVariable(Source)>?>> was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-null-safety

I tried to use `flattenLiveData()` but it is exspecting
`kotlin.collections.ArrayList<LiveData<List<TabDefinition>>>`
but I am passing in `Collection<LiveData<List<TypeVariable(Source)>?>>`

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is 
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<LiveData<List<TabDefinition>>> /* = 
java.util.ArrayList<LiveData<List<TabDefinition>>> */ but 
Collection<LiveData<List<TypeVariable(Source)>?>> was expected
```

flattenLiveData() is an inbuilt function.

```
/**
 * A helper function to convert a Collection<LiveData<List<Source>>> into a single 
 LiveData<List<Source>>.
 *
 * Ex. We have a list of TabProviders, each provider outputs a live data containing a 
  list of all of it's available tabs
  * we want to merge all of those into a single live data containing a single list.
 *
 * @param Source The inner data type
 * @param input A Collection of LiveData containing a List of source data
  * @return A LiveData containing a List of all source data from every element in 
 [input]
  */
 @JvmOverloads
  fun <Source> flattenLiveData(input: Collection<LiveData<List<Source>?>>, 
  waitForAllToBeNonNull: Boolean = false): LiveData<List<Source>> =
  CollectionMergerLiveData<List<Source>, List<Source>>(input, waitForAllToBeNonNull) 
  { 
      it.flatten() 
  }
```

Comment: Is `flattenLiveData` your own function or from a library? I've never heard of CollectionMergerLiveData. Kind of odd that is uses Collection instead of Iterable for the input, although I don't think that's the cause of the problem. I think I've seen this incorrect error message before--the compiler shows the wrong error message for the actual problem, but I can't remember what causes it. It would help to see the context of the code that's generating the error.

Comment: `flattenLiveData`is from a library.  I just copied the  function out

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because of generic types mismatch. Your original generic type `List<TabDefinition>` is not nullable:

```
val array: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<LiveData<List<TabDefinition>>> = getArray()
flattenLiveData(array) // Error "Type mismatch"
```

but `flattenLiveData` requires it to be nullable: `List<Source>?`. So changing this generic type to nullable (applying nullable operator `?`) will solve the problem:

```
val array: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<LiveData<List<TabDefinition>?>> = getArray()
flattenLiveData(array)
```